# How to view the git diff on a file?

Tags: linux, git, github

I cloned a git project into a folder on my desktop. I want to see the changes made on a certain file throughout its lifetime. I tried the

```
git log -- <filename>
```

command, yet this did not produce any output. I'm guessing that cloning a project does not necessarily clone the history as well? I can go on github and somewhat view the changes made to a file in a certain revision (yet this is polluted with the changes made in other files also). If anyone can give me point me in a general direction that would be great.

Comment: I think first checkout the branch/project with commit id and then do `git show` will help.

Comment: can you try git blame <file name> ?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, `git log -- <filename>` should display a list of commits. Can you post a link to the GH repository you want to use and an exact command you use?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a repository copies the entire history all the way back to the first commit.

One way to get there at the risk of overwhelming yourself with lots of detail from various contexts is

```
git log --all -- filename
```

To see the changes (or patches or deltas) made with each commit, run

```
git log --all --patch -- filename
```

When viewing patches, I generally do not want to see clutter from whitespace-only changes, so I run

```
git log --all --patch --ignore-all-space -- filename
```

To save a bit of typing, the above command is equivalent to

```
git log --all -p -w -- filename
```

Because of `--all`, this may show much more than you care about and will leave you to puzzle out which changes belong to which branch. To narrow it down, you can look at changes on a particular branch with

```
git log -p -w my-branch -- filename
```

or possibly a commit range as in

```
git log -p -w origin/master..master -- filename
```

You do not necessarily have to switch branches because `git log` has access to the entire repository.